# Silverlight Vertical only ScrollViewer?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, scrollviewer

Is there a way to create a ScrollViewer which only allows content to scroll vertically?  The horizontal (width) must be constrained in the same manner as a StackPanel's width is constrained to its parent (when HorizontalAlignment=Stretch).

I have a resizable window which contains content I want to allow to scroll vertically. The window contains a ScrollViewer. Inside there is a lot of TextBoxs (a data entry form).  When I type lots of text in a TextBox, the control just keeps growing to the right, and off the window.
If I use a StackPanel instead of a ScrollViewer, then the size of the TextBox remains the same no matter how much text is in there. (but then no vertical scrolling).

I cant set a hard-coded Width because the window is resizable.

So basically I want to constrain the ScrollViewer from growing in the Horizontal direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try setting

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

Comment: Wow. So simple. I cant believe I missed that.  I guess the "Visibility" part of HorizontalScrollBarVisibility property just made me think it would not affect the behavior of the scrollviewer, just the visibility of the scroll bar.

Comment: yeah i agree the name is confusing. :)